# Write links in a natural and optimized way using JavaScript and/or PHP

Tags: php, javascript, optimization, hyperlink

The admin users of a module that I'm developing want to add a functionality of automatically write links in the textarea(s) they fill.

For example, if they write:

> Please visit our page http://page.com

They want that http://page.com automatically is converted in a link:

```
<a href="http://page.com">http://page.com</a>
```

I want to do this in the best possible way in order of usability and performance.

I can't change the type of field (textarea) but I can do modifications with PHP and JavaScript that always is active (No Frameworks).

The users  frequently edit the fields and the links are only important when they "publish" the forms, because the content of those textarea(s)  are displayed inside an HTML table.

A textarea input could have more than one link.

I appreciate your opinions and points of view to resolve this common situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This RegEx is better since take care of the parameters passed in the URL and finish when the URL finish and don't take spaces or other following words.

```
(https?|ftp)://([-A-Z0-9.]+)(/[-A-Z0-9+&@#/%=~_|!:,.;]*)?(\?[A-Z0-9+&@#/%=~_|!:,.;]*)?
```

Any other suggestion to face up this situation? Use JavaScript or PHP? Any idea?

Comment: If your loading the data dynamically through ajax, javascript would be better in my opinion, but you could also apply the regex server side, right before passing the content to the client.

If you have static pages, which wont get changed after loading, markup the links with php before the page is loaded. With js you have a small delay, so links are clickable only after a small delay after page loaded.

Comment: I found this other, and is even better, since the last take points if they is at the end of the URL, not this: `(https?|ftp)://[-A-Z0-9+&@#/%?=~_|$!:,.;]*[A-Z0-9+&@#/%=~_|$]` But don't take attention of the rare URL with parens.

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion, you should handle this situation:

- using **PHP**,
- **after** reading the textarea contents from DB where it was stored,
- **before** sending the HTML output

I don't know the details of your application context and its users, but when you output any user input as HTML, you must take care of security issues as XSS attacks, and others.

If `$textarea_contents` is the variable where the textarea contents are (read from the DB), I would apply the `htmlspecialchars` function first:

```
$output = htmlspecialchars( $textarea_contents );
```

After this, you can parse the output string or use a regular expression to transform the URLs in anchor elements. You choice depends on the level of precision you want. A couple of choices are:

- http://code.iamcal.com/php/lib_autolink/lib_autolink.phps
- http://jmrware.com/articles/2010/linkifyurl/linkify.html

And it is good to know this recommended reading about the complex problem of linkifying strings (from the creator of Stack Overflow website):

- http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/10/the-problem-with-urls.html

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you, excellent references. In this case only a few admin users type the text in the textarea inputs.

Answer (score 1):

```
$code = preg_replace('/((https?|ftp):\/\/(?:[A-Z0-9-]+.)+[A-Z]{2,6}([\/?].+)?)/i','<a href="$1">$1</a>',$code);
```

([Regex Source](http://www.casibus.de/php/regex-url-validieren/))

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The use of regex is only part of the solution. For example, if I used only your code then when the user loads again the data from the DB he will see the html code.

Comment: Then just apply the regex when displaying the text on your website.

Comment: In that case maybe a JavaScript version is prefered.

Comment: Also, this regex wrap not only `http://url.com` but also the next words until a dot appears.